# scipy spherical harmonics imaginary part

Tags: python, scipy

In the documentation of scipy(http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.sph_harm.html) it clearly states that *scipy.special.sph_harm* returns a complex float. given by the expression shown in the link. When trying trying to insert some values however, i keep on getting only a negligible value of what is expected.

The real(ie. not imaginary) value I believe is something closer to the absolute value expected if you compute the mathematical expression in the link:

```
from scipy.special import sph_harm,lpmv
m=2;n=5;th=2.1;ph=0.4
print(sph_harm(m,n,th,ph))
#returns (0.36574435883734352+2.5429495084534193e-310j) (essentially no imag.part

def norm(m,n): #sqrt part
  return np.sqrt((2*n+1)/(4*np.pi) * \
    np.math.factorial(n-m)/np.math.factorial(n+m))
def ie(m,theta): #imaginary exponential part
  return np.exp(1j*m*theta)
out=norm(m,n)*ie(m,th)*lpmv(m,n,np.cos(ph)) #lpmv=legendre
print(out,abs(out))
#returns (-0.179310129764-0.31877392206j) 0.365744358837
```

Is there something wrong with the sph_harm or am I somehow using it wrong?

I am using scipy v0.15.1

Comment: Strange.  I just tried an assortment of scipy versions that I have handy (0.11.0, 0.16.0, and the latest develop version from github), and in all cases `sph_harm(2, 5, 2.1, 0.4)` returns something within a few ULPs of `(-0.17931012976432356-0.31877392205957022j)`.

Comment: Strange. I am currently using a python version Python 3.4.3 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)|. Could this make a difference?

Comment: I just downgraded my anaconda installation to use scipy 0.15.1 (and numpy 1.9.3), and I still get the correct answer from `sph_harm(2, 5, 2.1, 0.4)`.  If you run `from scipy import special; special.test()`, do all the tests pass?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser No. It seems 6/703 tests fail, where 2 of these are sph_harm tests. I guess I need to reinstall it. Thanks

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser It seems reinstalling did not work. At this point I'm wondering whether it's hardware-related... Any idea what I could do from here?

Comment: If you are using stock anaconda, then you should report the problem to the anaconda developers.

Comment: Tested in Anaconda 2.3.0, python 2.7.10, scipy 0.16.0, and the result seems correct.

Comment: See https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/5376